# What does this objective C syntax mean?

Tags: objective-c, nsbundle

I'm new to objective-C. Can someone explain what does this code mean?

```
title = NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"DFUSuccessAlertTitle",
                                                              @"DFU",
                                                              [NSBundle mainBundle],
                                                              @"Success",
                                                              @"Title in firmware update on complete");
```

Specifically, what is this NSBundle thing?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=NSBundle You couldn't Google this?

Comment: @SO  the OP is probably asking about the meaning of `[NSBundle mainBundle]` in this context.

Comment: @MattBall Fair enough, the question should be a bit more specific then I guess, but point taken.

Comment: Why are you guys so mean here? It's a legitimate question.Yes, I was asking about the meaning of [NSBundle mainBundle]. If you read the google results, you'll see that it doesn't help me understand that piece of code at all

Answer (score 0):

`[NSBundle mainBundle]` is [the basic message-passing syntax in Objective-C.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html)